# SQLITE_CANTOPEN - windows c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite, window

I am trying to create an Sqlite database in the selected folder but can`t do this.

Operating System - Windows, editor - Visual studio, progect encoding is unicode. Encoding of input string with database connection unknown. Language - C++

The problem:
I can't create database when I use following connection string: `file:C:/Users/Public/Desktop/testDb.sqlite`

I am always getting **error 14 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN)**.

I use following function to create database:

```
CSqliteManager::CSqliteManager(const char* dbName)
{
    db = nullptr;
    int rc = sqlite3_open(dbName, &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        db = nullptr;
    }
}
```

How should me change connection string to create database fo the sollowing pass:
C://Users/Public/Desctop/MyBD.sqlite

Answer (score 1):

You can't use URI style filenames with `sqlite3_open()` as they're disabled by default (I'm assuming you didn't enable them globally). Instead you need to use `sqlite3_open_v2()` with the appropriate option (`SQLITE_OPEN_URI`). [Details](https://www.sqlite.org/uri.html) and [more details](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#urifilenamesinsqlite3open).

(Or just not use a URI, of course)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it couldn't help me. I read the links you provided, tried to open database using url and simple file path (that is better to use for me), but got the same problem. May be you are able to give me working example how to open database in the selected folder under windows OS or suggest any think else? I am trying to solve thisproblem duaring last 3 days and have no idea why I always getthe same exception...

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar `int rc = sqlite3_open("C:/Users/Public/Desktop/testDb.sqlite", &db);` You have to have permission to open and create files in C:/Users/Public/Desktop (And that directory must already exist, of course.)

Comment: thank you very much. I got 2 problems: 1 is read/write permition and the second if - connection string encoding. Now everythink works.